# Getting a single JSON Object in an Array

Tags: javascript, json

I have some json files that have an array structure like this:

```
{
    "00_85_03.g1t": {
        "hash": "a05dc5727ee4a3d80202e7ce5c89168d",
        "file_name": "00_85_03.g1t",
        "version": "0",
        "cacheclear_flag": 1,
        "bundle_flag": 0,
        "directory": "0000",
        "firstflag": 0,
        "size": 476380
    },
    "00_85_03_36th.g1t": {
        "hash": "5d28224aa1f594c249da69a1976cc5b6",
        "file_name": "00_85_03_36th.g1t",
        "version": "0",
        "cacheclear_flag": 1,
        "bundle_flag": 0,
        "directory": "0000",
        "firstflag": 0,
        "size": 831960
    },
    "00_85_03_all_battle.g1t": {
        "hash": "ca654ed300998d97e96480cabcac4035",
        "file_name": "00_85_03_all_battle.g1t",
        "version": "0",
        "cacheclear_flag": 1,
        "bundle_flag": 0,
        "directory": "0000",
        "firstflag": 0,
        "size": 700872
    } 
}
```

I would like to make a single variable with all "hash" values. I'm using Google App Scripts to insert them into a spreadsheet. So far, I'm able to get a list of the keys but struggling to pull the "hash" value from them. I'm sure it's easier than I'm making it but just learning JS. Here is as far as I was able to make it my result output.

```
function chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size){
    var index = 0;
    var arrayLength = myArray.length;
    var tempArray = [];
    
    for (index = 0; index < arrayLength; index += chunk_size) {
        myChunk = myArray.slice(index, index+chunk_size);
        // Do something if you want with the group
        tempArray.push(myChunk);
    }

    return tempArray;
}

function flatten(arrayOfArrays){
  return [].concat.apply([], arrayOfArrays);
}

function showPickerJP() {
  var rows = [Object.keys(json)]; 
  var toRows = rows[0].length;
  var rowsflate = flatten(rows);
  var rowstocols  = chunkArray(rowsflate, 1);
  var results = [];
  for(var i=0; i<toRows; i++){
    results[i] = (rowstocols[i]);
      }
  var hashvalues = chunkArray(results,1);
  Logger.log(hashvalues);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: what exactly do you need from the data?

Comment: Aren't arrays defined with []?

Comment: `Object.values(json).map(x => x.hash)` ? Or `Array.from(Object.values(json), x => x.hash)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the `hash` values from the json data you can use map, ass follows:

```
const hashList = Object.values(json).map(item => item.hash);
```

```js
const json = {
    "00_85_03.g1t": {
        "hash": "a05dc5727ee4a3d80202e7ce5c89168d",
        "file_name": "00_85_03.g1t",
        "version": "0",
        "cacheclear_flag": 1,
        "bundle_flag": 0,
        "directory": "0000",
        "firstflag": 0,
        "size": 476380
    },
    "00_85_03_36th.g1t": {
        "hash": "5d28224aa1f594c249da69a1976cc5b6",
        "file_name": "00_85_03_36th.g1t",
        "version": "0",
        "cacheclear_flag": 1,
        "bundle_flag": 0,
        "directory": "0000",
        "firstflag": 0,
        "size": 831960
    },
    "00_85_03_all_battle.g1t": {
        "hash": "ca654ed300998d97e96480cabcac4035",
        "file_name": "00_85_03_all_battle.g1t",
        "version": "0",
        "cacheclear_flag": 1,
        "bundle_flag": 0,
        "directory": "0000",
        "firstflag": 0,
        "size": 700872
    } 
};

const hashList = Object.values(json).map(item => item.hash);
console.log({ hashList })
```